# How do i make my row responsive so when on mobile it goes vertical?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a row responsive in a way that mobile rows go vertically instead of horizontal and I still have all those fancy boxes, could anyone help me in any way?

I already tried changing the columns up, css-flexbox, but I'm most likely just doing something horribly wrong.

```css
#caixas {
  background-color: #58373791;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#caixas2 {
  background-color: #b6696a91;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#border {
  border: solid 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
  <div id="border" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
        <div id="caixas" class="container">
          <h3 class="h2sm" align="center">Estudante </h3>
          <h4 class="h1sm " align="center">Português</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="caixas2" class="container">
          <h3 class="h3sm" align="center">Portuguese Student</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
        <div id="caixas" class="container">
          <h3 class="h2sm" align="center">Estudante </h3>
          <h4 class="h1sm " align="center">Internacional</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="caixas2" class="container">
          <h3 class="h3sm" align="center">Internacional Student</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
        <div id="caixas" class="container">
          <h3 class="h2sm" align="center">Estudante </h3>
          <h4 class="h1sm " align="center">Intercâmbio</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="caixas2" class="container">
          <h3 class="h3sm" align="center">Exchange Student</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What solution you want? not understand you question.

Comment: What you want to do? i don't get it.

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear, i want for the rows to be vertical when its on mobile

Comment: I'm guessing from your classes that you're using bootstrap grids? What does *rows go vertically* mean? Responsive design shouldn't be concerned with "mobile" or not mobile. It's about screen size.

Comment: Hi @JoãoAlmeida, i think you just need to include col-12, so that they will stack on mobile devices. So your divs within your ```.row``` should read ```<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">``` instead of ```<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">```.